# How to load more on PHP array?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I use jQuery (I found this code in an answer, tested and working) to show *people.php* and reload it every 100 seconds. *People.php* has an array `peoples` where there are saved name, job, birthday.

As you can see, the output stops at 30 names. How can I have a twitter like button "load more" and show 10 more at a time? Additionally, when there are e.g. 50 more people's name (assuming that the user clicked "load more" twice, will the jQuery timeout reload, returned them at 30 as the beginning ?

```
<script>
var timerID;

$(function () {
    function loadfeed() {
        $('#feed')
            .addClass('loading')
            .load('people.php', function () {
                $(this).removeClass('loading');
                timerID = setTimeout(loadfeed, 100000);
        });
    }

    loadfeed();
});
</script>
```

Comment: @wukong Because on index.php I need to reload the people.php

Comment: @wukong:  Looks like the intent is to refresh the feed every 100 seconds.

Comment: @OpenSourceLover I did, but all the results have to do with mySQL

Comment: use array_slice if your data is stored in php array http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well what you could do is save a variable that contains the number of people, this example should give you a good view of what i mean.

```
<script>
var timerID;
var cap;

$(function () {
    function loadfeed() {
        $('#feed')
            .addClass('loading')
            .load('people.php?cap='+cap, function () {
                $(this).removeClass('loading');
                timerID = setTimeout(loadfeed, 100000);
        });
    }

    loadfeed();
});
</script>

<?php
    foreach ($peoples as $people) {
    if(++$i > $_GET['cap']) break;

    echo $people->name;

    }
?>
```

So all you have to do, is change the cap variable, you could do this easily making a javascript function and call this via a onClick event.

Comment: I tried this     `$("#loadmore").click(function() {
        cap += 10;
    });` but it doesnt seem to work...

Comment: Just make something like function f(new_cap) { cap = new_cap } en call it somewhere on a button or image with onClick="javascript:f;"

Answer (score 1):

How about passing a parameter to the URL in your `load(..)` call?

```
$(function () {
    var startAt = 0;
    function loadfeed() {
        $('#feed')
            .addClass('loading')
            .load('people.php?start_at=' + startAt, function () {
                $(this).removeClass('loading');
                timerID = setTimeout(loadfeed, 100000);
                startAt += 30;
            });
    }
});
```

Then in people.php you could get the passed parameter using `$_GET`:

```
$start_at = 0;
if (isset($_GET['start_at']) && is_numeric($_GET['start_at'])) {
    $start_at = (int) $_GET['start_at'];
}
for ($i = $start_at; $i < min($start_at + 30, sizeof($peoples)); $i++) {
    echo $peoples[$i]->name;
}
```

Comment: I am testing it right now, however how does the "load more" will work?